Minimum number of teeth to avoid interference in gears
The number of teeth required on mating pinion and wheel gears to avoid interference is given as:

Now, the minimum number of teeth on pinion gear in rack and pinion set is given as:

For a pinion-rack arrangement, the gear ratio (G) can be said to be tending to infinity. When we substitute this in the equation for number of teeth on wheel gear in pinion-wheel, why don't we get the equation for minimum number of teeth on pinion in rack and pinion arrangement?
